# Pass some text with javascript into WebView from Xamarin.Forms

Tags: javascript, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, android-webview

I try to send some text into a webView control from xamarin.forms. There are plenty of solution, which I almost all tried... ;-)

So actually they work great, but I have always to click a button on the html file, which I load into this webView, that I can pass some text into the html file. But I would like to pass the text without clicking on this button. The Text should be there, when the webView has loaded.

Here some code:

In the xaml.cs I load the WebView:

```
  protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        webViewElement.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        webViewElement.Source = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();

        webViewElement.RegisterAction(ExecuteActionFromJavascript);

        ExecuteSetFromJavascript();
    }
```

then with ExecuteSetFromJavascript() i call a function which is in the html file:

```
  private async void ExecuteSetFromJavascript()
    {
        var result = "Hello";
        if (result != null)
        {
          var test =  await webViewElement.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync($"updatetextonwebview('{result}')");
        }
    }
```

this is the function in the html file:

```
  function updatetextonwebview(text) {

                                alert(text);

                                   // document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = text;
                                }
```

So now the page should Alert "Hello" when the updatetextonwebview is called.

but that doesn't make it. Maybe the html page is not ready when i call this funciton!

Does anyone have an idea how I can get to my solution?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution now is: in the HybridWebView I added a property

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CustomRenderer

{
    public class HybridWebView : WebView
    {
        Action<string> action;

        public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "Uri",
            returnType: typeof(string),
            declaringType: typeof(HybridWebView),
            defaultValue: default(string));

        public static BindableProperty QuestionProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "Question",
            returnType: typeof(string),
            declaringType: typeof(HybridWebView),
            defaultValue: default(string));

        public static BindableProperty AnswerProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "Answer",
            returnType: typeof(string),
            declaringType: typeof(HybridWebView),
            defaultValue: default(string));

        public string Uri
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
        }

        public string Question
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(QuestionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(QuestionProperty, value); }
        }

        public string Answer
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(AnswerProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AnswerProperty, value); }
        }

        public void RegisterAction(Action<string> callback)
        {
            action = callback;
        }

        public void Cleanup()
        {
            action = null;
        }

        public void InvokeAction(string data)
        {
            if (action == null || data == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            action.Invoke(data);
        }
    }
}
```

which I can access in the JavaScriptWebViewClient and on the OnPageFinished I can submit the data to the webPage.

```cs
  public class JavascriptWebViewClient : FormsWebViewClient
{
    string _javascript;
    string _question;
    private string _answer;

    public JavascriptWebViewClient(HybridWebViewRenderer renderer, string javascript, string question, string answer) : base(renderer)
    {
        _javascript = javascript;
        _answer = answer;
        _question = question;
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);


        view.EvaluateJavascript($"factorial({_question}, {_answer})", null);

        view.EvaluateJavascript(_javascript, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is being called a **HybridWebView**. This means that it can both receive and send data.

I see a lot of inconsistencies and issues with the code that you have provided - why do you configure the WebView in OnAppearing, why is the source being set twice, etc.

Since the provided code is not enough and full of issues and questions - instead of trying to figure out where it did go wrong, you should follow the official guide for creating a *HybridWebView* from Microsoft - [Customizing a WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview).

This is working and also you have the end solution in GitHub available [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/HybridWebView).

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask them, but I feel that the guide is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, and yes I know that I need this HybbridWebView and I know this page from Microsoft. But the thing is that it needs first an interaction on de Webpage that you can send some Data to it. My question was, how can i load the webpage without the interaction in the webpage and submit the data. I want to fill a textbox and the textbox should be filled after loading the page, not when i first habe to click a button.

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot understand you. Please look again the the sample app - there the code is being invoked after a button have been pressed. Instead of pressing a button, yoiu can invoke the same command yourself.

Comment: ok maybe I have tomatoes on my eyes or I don't understand how I can invoke the command from the app that it will fill some text from the App in this textbox on the webpage.